# What's the purpose of the attribute in parentheses on ints in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, types

According to the documentation, the attribute in the parentheses (e.g. the "3" in SMALLINT(3)) is supposed to constrain the display of the values of the SMALLINT to three digits. However, when I inserted five test numbers (9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999), it took each number at its full value rather than capping it at the three digits and displayed it accordingly (except for 99999, of course, which it capped at 32767). Shouldn't the numbers be limited, at least while being displayed, to three digits? Or am I missing the true purpose here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For integer types, the attribute relates to display width and can only be seen if you add zerofill to the column create statement.

Display width does not effect the storage allocated to the column, only the padded display when zerofill is enabled.

See also this explanation: http://matthom.com/archive/2006/11/28/mysql-integer-columns-and-display-width

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/data-types.html):

> ***`M`*** indicates the maximum display width for integer types. For floating-point and fixed-point types, ***`M`*** is the total number of digits that can be stored (the precision). For string types, ***`M`*** is the maximum length. The maximum permissible value of ***`M`*** depends on the data type.

Further, as stated [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-type-attributes.html):

> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, [`INT(4)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html) specifies an [`INT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html) with a display width of four digits. This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)
>
> The display width does *not* constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column specified as [`SMALLINT(3)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html) has the usual [`SMALLINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html) range of `-32768` to `32767`, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits.
>
> When used in conjunction with the optional (nonstandard) attribute `ZEROFILL`, the default padding of spaces is replaced with zeros. For example, for a column declared as [`INT(4) ZEROFILL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html), a value of `5` is retrieved as `0005`.
>
> > **Note**
> >     The `ZEROFILL` attribute is ignored when a column is involved in expressions or [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) queries.
> >
> > If you store values larger than the display width in an integer column that has the `ZEROFILL` attribute, you may experience problems when MySQL generates temporary tables for some complicated joins. In these cases, MySQL assumes that the data values fit within the column display width.
>
> All integer types can have an optional (nonstandard) attribute `UNSIGNED`. Unsigned type can be used to permit only nonnegative numbers in a column or when you need a larger upper numeric range for the column. For example, if an [`INT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html) column is `UNSIGNED`, the size of the column's range is the same but its endpoints shift from `-2147483648` and `2147483647` up to `0` and `4294967295`.
>
> Floating-point and fixed-point types also can be `UNSIGNED`. As with integer types, this attribute prevents negative values from being stored in the column. Unlike the integer types, the upper range of column values remains the same.
>
> If you specify `ZEROFILL` for a numeric column, MySQL automatically adds the `UNSIGNED` attribute to the column.
>
> Integer or floating-point data types can have the additional attribute `AUTO_INCREMENT`. When you insert a value of `NULL` (recommended) or `0` into an indexed `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the column is set to the next sequence value. Typically this is ***`value`***`+ 1`, where value is the largest ***`value`*** for the column currently in the table. `AUTO_INCREMENT` sequences begin with `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, but that was all copy-pasted from the manual. In general, the parentheses make sense (like on DOUBLES and such), but specifically on numeric types like INT and SMALLINT, the attribute doesn't seem to effect the entry at all. A value higher than the attribute should allow are stored fine, and when queried, the entries still return the full value rather than constrained for display purposes, which the manual seemed to say it would do. In these cases, it seems like the attribute is rather useless in this implementation.

Comment: @Abion47: The manual explains all of that (re `ZEROFILL`); I pasted from the manual because, really, you should have read that before you posted here and asked specific questions with reference to it if there was something you didn't understand...

Comment: I did read it before, and I posted here because I didn't quite understand it, but I do understand that there are a lot of people who post on here that don't do research before hand.